# Getting timeout error with Gocql

Tags: go, cassandra, timeout, gocql

I am getting following errors while inserting data in Cassandra.
I am using `gocql` client for Cassandra.

> {"error":"gocql: too many query timeouts on the connection","status":500}
>
> {"error":"gocql: no response received from cassandra within timeout period","status":500}
>
> {"error":"write tcp 172.23.15.226:36954-\u003e172.23.16.15:9042: use of closed network connection","status":500}

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Please check your network connection, if you can se the server network, and if the server is up and running.

Comment: Hi, all cassandra server are running . it is giving timeout error when i am running a load test

Comment: What you mean by "load test"?

Comment: I am running a Jmeter load test on an api which is inserting data to cassandra (3 node cluster ), the test passes for initial few seconds after that it start giving error because of timeouts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to increase timeouts in Cassandra config file (**write_request_timeout_in_ms** - for writes) and concurrent writes (**concurrent_writes**).

Also, try to lower **NumConns** parameter in your gocql driver.
If you are using goroutines, try to lower their number and verify that you are reusing same session object for all goroutines.

If you are using protocol version prior to 4, you can try to set **Timeout** paramter of cluster object in gocql to higher value.